# Java Button Full Screen

Tags: java, user-interface, button, textarea

ScreenShot when running the code
[image: ScreenShot when running the code]

When I run the code, the okButton does not follow my dimensions and appears on the full Screen.

Additionally, I noticed that when the cursor is inside the okButton method, then the button seems to follow my dimensions.

What has gone wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;

public class WindowGui extends Frame {

public static TextArea tx ;
public static Button okButton;

public WindowGui(){

    Window();

    TextArea();

    okButton();

    this.addWindowListener(new CloseWindowAndExit());
}

public void Window(){
    //this.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.setSize(1600,900);
    this.setTitle("LogicGate Simulator");
    this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    this.toFront();
    this.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("kamerja");
}

public void TextArea(){

    tx = new TextArea("kalimeres",2,30);

    tx.setText("Σύντομες Οδηγίες LogicGate Simulator");
    tx.setEditable(false);
    tx.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    tx.setEditable(false);
    this.add(tx);

    System.out.println("kaliSSmerja");
}

public void okButton(){
    okButton = new Button ("OK");
    okButton.setSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    okButton.setLocation(500, 350);
    okButton.setFont(new Font ("Times New Roman",Font.PLAIN,14));
    this.add(okButton);
}
}
```

Comment: You should really consider using the Layout components, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html, then you will easy get your desired result within the limits of a GUI interface. Setting location on buttons ecc is not the correct way....

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the problem with your code is that you are not using JFrame to create the frame, by doing this your code will work.(I've edited your code and posted it below for you!).

Main Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class NewClass extends Frame {

public static TextArea tx ;
public static Button okButton;
public static JFrame frame;

public static void NewClass(){

Window();

TextArea();

okButton();


}

public static void Window(){
//this.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(1600,900);
frame.setTitle("LogicGate Simulator");
frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
frame.toFront();
frame.setVisible(true);

System.out.println("kamerja");
}

public static void TextArea(){

tx = new TextArea("kalimeres",2,30);

tx.setText("Σύντομες Οδηγίες LogicGate Simulator");
tx.setEditable(false);
tx.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
tx.setEditable(false);
frame.add(tx);

System.out.println("kaliSSmerja");
}

public static void okButton(){
okButton = new Button ("OK");
okButton.setSize(new Dimension(50,50));
okButton.setLocation(500, 350);
okButton.setFont(new Font ("Times New Roman",Font.PLAIN,14));
frame.add(okButton);
} 
}
```

Run Code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class StackOverflowHelpAnswers extends NewClass{
public static class okButtonListener implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

}
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    //do something
    NewClass();
}
}
```

Comment: Also if you found this helpful, could you please accept this as the answer, it would help alot Thanks!